# Float value not being correctly persisted to database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, floating-point

I have a Grails application in which I'm parsing an XML file and using the parsed data to create objects and persist them to a MySQL database.

One of my classes has a `Float` property:

```
class Foo {
    // ...
    Float myFloat

    static constraints = {
        myFloat(scale: 9) // Trying to specify 9 digits of precision, but this doesn't seem to be making any difference
    }

    // ...
}
```

While parsing the XML I come to an attribute with the value of `6378137`.  I want to assign that value to `myFloat`:

```
class MyService{
    // ...

    def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(myXmlFile.getText())

    def foo = new Foo(
        myFloat: xml.attribute("my_float")?.toFloat()
    ).save()

    // ...
}
```

At this point in the debugger I can see the value of `myFloat` is `6378137.0`.  The problem is that after the transaction commits the value stored in the database is `6378140`.

**Why isn't `myFloat` being stored with the value I assign to it?**

Comment: What is the datatype of the underlying column?

Comment: @JamesKleeh the data type is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set precision and scale in GORM/hibernate..

look into the below link ...

http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/appfuse-user-hibernate-and-decimal-column-precision-td548279.html

Comment: This gives me some idea of what is going on, but I'm having a hard time translating your answer into Grails terms.  I have attempted to use [scale](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/scale.html), but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  Any ideas?